# I created a list in class a and now I want to add something to this list in class B

Tags: c#

```
class A
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<RootJson> eList = new List<RootJson>();
        RootJson rootjson = new RootJson();
        Libs.B.Get();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static void Get()
    {
        rootjson.Hub = new List<Hub>();
        Hub hub = new Hub();
        hub.OS = "1.1";
        rootjson.Hub.Add(rootjson.hub);
    }
}
```

The problem is that rootjson is in Class A and not available in Class B. How can I make this available?
I want to keep the creation of rootjson in Class A, because I also want create Class C,D and E, which will also be adding stuff to rootjson.

How do i declare rootjson in Class B in this case?

Comment: use properties to enable access to other classes. whether that is **static** properties or **instance** properties is up to you to decide.

Comment: can you elaborate Ousmane? I don't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it to the argument list of your `Get` command (assuming that's where you will use it), and then pass it from `A` to `B` through that parameter:

```
class A
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<RootJson> eList = new List<RootJson>();
        RootJson rootjson = new RootJson();
        Libs.B.Get(rootjson);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static void Get(RootJson rootJson)
    {
        // Do something if rootJson is null
        if (rootJson == null) rootJson = new RootJson();

        rootJson.Hub = new List<Hub>();
        Hub hub = new Hub();
        hub.OS = "1.1";
        rootJson.Hub.Add(hub);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways you can go about this:

1- you should instantiate a variable of RootJson in the classes that you want, than add what you need to it.

2- If you will be constantly working with the same object of type RootJson, than make a class to keep track and modify the RootJson object, than simply use inheritance in all other classes to access and modify as needed

taste of Inheritance explained below:

Your question is about class inheritance. When creating methods or variables in a class you have three choices: public, protected, and private. 
Say you need to access some stuff that are in class A, Make the variables, and/or methods that need to be accessed protected like so:

in class A:

```
protected int GetNextID();
```

Next step is to tell class B where to find the methods or variables your refering to, this is called the scope, you need to do the following in class B:

```
public class B : A
{

}
```

finally you can use the methods of class A in class B, by just calling it

```
ID = GetNextID();
```

for more information look at class inheritance [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)